# Google Analytics: How to anonymize GA tracking so that 'Region' is not known but 'Country' is still known?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy

Because of data privacy regulations (in Europe) we must not be able to locate an individual customer fro GA data.

Our application (which implements GA) is only used by a specific industry sector. Because of this in a given Region there may only be one customer.
So if we knew the Region we would often be able to locate the customer.

Now as a google analytics developer: How can I anonymize tracking so that region is not known but country is still known?

I am using GA anonymizeIP (which clears the IP's leat significant octet), but still from this anonymized IP I can get the Region.

Thanks in advance for any helpful Information.

Comment: Not via code, but you can set a filter in the view setting  (custom filter/search and replace on the region and city fields and set it to some neutral value).

Answer (score 0):

Filters as suggested by @eike-pierstorff would work but it sounds like the customers might be larger companies so you might also need to neutralize the ISP/Network field which could identify the company more directly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.
Now this is my own solution:

Do IP Override and Geographical Override.
Now in order to set Geographical Override we would need to do get to know country on the client side.
For this a Geolocation webservice can be used (called by the Client App) the webservice would take the requesters IP and return the Country (from the IP) and the requesters IP.
The Client App would then mask the IP the way we like for IP Override and pass Country for Geographical Override.

There are Geolocation web-services providing the needed information - but probably not free of costs. 
Alternatively we could implement such a Gelocation webservice ourselves, the implementation could incorporate a free version of GeoIPCountryWhois.csv.